# Linq Getting Customers group by date and then by their type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am working on generating report for showing customer using LINQ in C#. I want to show no. of customers of each type.

There are 3 types of customer registered, guest and manager. I want to group by customers by registered date and then by type of customer. i.e If today 3 guest, 4 registered and 2 manager are inserted. and tomorrow 4,5 and 6 are registered resp. then report should show Number of customers registerd on the day . separate row for each type.

```
DATE        TYPEOF CUSTOMER    COUNT
31-10-2013  GUEST              3
31-10-2013  REGISTERED         4
31-10-2013  MANAGER            2
30-10-2013  GUEST              5
30-10-2013  REGISTERED         10
30-10-2013  MANAGER            3
```

LIKE THIS .

```
var subquery = from eat in _customerRepo.Table
                           group eat by new { yy = eat.CreatedOnUTC.Value.Year, mm = eat.CreatedOnUTC.Value.Month, dd = eat.CreatedOnUTC.Value.Day } into g
                           select new { Id = g.Min(x => x.Id) };




var query = from c in _customerRepo.Table
                        join cin in subquery.Distinct() on c.Id equals cin.Id
                        select c;
```

By above query I get minimum cutomers registerd on that day
Thanks in advance

Comment: `_customerRepo.Table.GroupBy(x=>new {x.Date,x.Type});` and you will have them grouped by two properties

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
var query = _customerRepo.Table
     .GroupBy(c => new {Date = c.Date.Date,  Type = c.TypeOfCustomer})
     .Select(g => new 
                   {
                       Date = g.Key.Date,
                       Type = g.Key.Type, 
                       Count = g.Count
                   }
            )
     .OrderByDescending (r = r.Date);
```

Comment: what if i want to take each and every column from the table!?

Comment: @Nitinvarpe What you mean?

Comment: There are some other common properties for customer which i want to show in report but not want to group by those parameters. Or can i write extension method for Igrouping i.e g

Comment: I believe it's `g.Count()`, not `g.Count`

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from c in _customerRepo.Table
            group c by new { c.TypeOfCustomer, c.Date } into g
            orderby g.Key.Date descending,
                    g.Key.TypeOfCustomer == "GUEST" ? 1 :
                    g.Key.TypeOfCustomer == "REGISTERED" ? 2 : 3
            select new {
               g.Key.Date,
               g.Key.TypeOfCustomer,
               Count = g.Count()
            };
```

You can remove second ordering if it's not required for daily results to be in order guest > registered > manager:

```
var query = from c in _customerRepo.Table
            group c by new { c.TypeOfCustomer, c.Date } into g
            orderby g.Key.Date descending
            select new {
               g.Key.Date,
               g.Key.TypeOfCustomer,
               Count = g.Count()
            };
```

Comment: Its working but now what if i want to take each and every column from the table!?

Comment: @Nitinvarpe you can only select grouping keys and aggregated values.

Comment: Isnt there any solution to this, to select all columns i.e. their phonenumber, address, emailid?

Comment: @Nitinvarpe which email you want to show in first row, if you have three guests in that row?

Comment: Thing is that I have some different properties assigned to customers.Which i want show I only gave u example which i thought was wrong so beg ur pardon!!!

Comment: @Nitinvarpe no problem :) Linq works exactly as SQL - you are allowed to select values you are grouping by or aggregate functions

Comment: Can I call some other extension method of g just like g.Count(), by writing custom method if yes where should i write it?

Comment: @Nitinvarpe nope, you can't call custom methods if you are working with linq to entities (because ef will not be able to convert it to SQL cod). Either move calculation to client side (but that will require transferring all data to client PC) or use only [supported methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)