# LINQ Multiple Group By in a List<T> then convert to List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following class

```
public class Person
{
  public string ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string District {get; set;}
  public string Level {get; set;}
}
```

Then on my function, I am writing a LINQ to group a list of Person, by District then by Level, into a new list of the same type (Person)

I want to write it in a way that i will not use var (making it an anonymous type) and new:

Something like

```
List<Person> persons; \\this already has values
List<Person> grpByP = persons
  .GroupBy()
  .ToList<Person>(); \\ Linq query to group persons list by District and Level
```

I just don't know how to write the grpByP LINQ query.

**UPDATE**:  I want the ID and the Name be retained in the values of the grpByP variable because using anonymous type will only include the District and Level.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _"by Distinct"_ you mean by `District`?

Comment: If you group persons by district and level, you are bound to have multiple distinct lists of persons, not just one list.

Comment: @SeM - corrected it.

Comment: here is an example of group by with 2 variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703034/linq-getting-customers-group-by-date-and-then-by-their-type

Comment: What's wrong with using `var`?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your desired output given a small input ?

Comment: Reopened because there's another part of the question that isn't addressed by the duplicate: "not using var" and "converting to `List<Person>`.

Comment: `.GroupBy(person => new {person.District, person.Level})`

Comment: I dont understand this. What means "making it an anonymous type"? You don't want a `List<Person>`? How you want to fill the groups into a single `List<Person>` at all? I would understand it if you wanted a `List<List<Person>>` for example or a `Dictionary<string, List<Person>>`.

Comment: Grouping and converting back to a list of the original type is the equivalent of simply sorting the original list. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @Enigmativity I think that's it. Any code that can serve the purpose is something I'll accept.

Comment: @Joseph - What do you mean by "using anonymous type will only include the District and Level"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're after something like this...

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person()
    {
        ID = "1",
        Name = "Joe",
        District = "Columbia",
        Level = "10"
    },
    new Person()
    {
        ID = "2",
        Name = "Beth",
        District = "Columbia",
        Level = "10"
    },
    new Person()
    {
        ID = "3",
        Name = "Jim",
        District = "Washington",
        Level = "11"
    }
};  //this already has values
var grpByP = persons
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.District, p.Level })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        People = g.ToList<Person>()
    });

foreach (var g in grpByP)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group:");
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key.District);
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key.Level);
    Console.WriteLine("People:");
    foreach (Person p in g.People)
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:-

> Group: 
>   Columbia 10 
>   People: 
>   Joe 
>   Beth
>
> Group: 
>   Washington 11 
>   People: 
>   Jim

Comment: It's not what you asked for though. You need to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds from comments like you just want to order your list by district, then by level. This is easy enough

```
List<Person> result = persons.OrderBy(p => p.District).ThenBy(p => p.Level).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

[The question for which this one had been originally marked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703034/linq-getting-customers-group-by-date-and-then-by-their-type) already explains how to use `GroupBy`. I'll address the second part: "converting to `List<Person>`" and "not using `var`".

First, about converting the result of `GroupBy` to `List<Person>`: you can't do that. The result of the `GroupBy` operation is a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String,Person>>` (assuming you are grouping by a `string` property), which is itself an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<Person>`; each of these inner `IEnumerable<Person>` corresponds to each of the keys found, and you can check the key for each case with the `Key` property:

```
var grouped = persons.GroupBy(p => p.District);
foreach(var group in grouped) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"People in disctrict {group.Key}:");
    foreach(var person in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
    }
}
```

You *could* go back to get the full list of ungrouped people, but I'd say that doesn't make much sense:

```
var ungrouped = grouped.SelectMany(g => g).ToList<Person>();
```

And about not using `var`: you certainly could define the variable as `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String,Person>>`, but I don't see what would be the benefit of doing that.

**Edit:** All of this doesn't apply if as other answers suggest what you actually want to do is to *sort* your data, not to *group* it.

**Edit** per your comment: *"I want the ID and the Name be retained in the values of the grpByP variable because using anonymous type will only include the District and Level*" - `GroupBy` will not create anonymous objects, it will keep the original objects that you supplied (see my example above). Anonymous objects would be created only if you did something like `.Select(p => new {p.Discrict})` in the resulting groups.