# Linq grouping by multiple columns - issue

Tags: c#, linq

I seem to be running into an issue with what is probably a very simple task (forgive my newbie-ness with linq and c#).

I want to use linq to query an EF DB context.  As part of this, I want to group by a few columns, then store these results into a list object.

I currently have this:

```
var Orders = orderSqlContext.OrderDetails
                .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    x.OrderNumber,
                    x.OrderTotal
                })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.OrderNumber,
                    x.OrderTotal
                }).ToList
```

I end up with errors on the two columns in the "select" portion above.

*"OrderDetails does not contain a definition for OrderNumber and no extension method OrderNumber accepting a first argument of type IGrouping [...] could be found."*

Basically, the OrderDetails context would normally return a list of orders with extra records for each line item on them.  I want to also have a list of the distinct orders in that context.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the solution is described here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703034/linq-getting-customers-group-by-date-and-then-by-their-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703034/linq-getting-customers-group-by-date-and-then-by-their-type)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the [`Key` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2.key?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the group:

```
var Orders = orderSqlContext.OrderDetails
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.OrderNumber,
        x.OrderTotal
    })
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        grp.Key.OrderNumber,
        grp.Key.OrderTotal
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Rango.  After making the tweak to have the "select" columns use the key property as you've shown above, the entire block of code is giving me the error "cannot assign 'method group' to anonymous type property."  Any idea why?

Comment: @j.kiel: maybe a property/field is not accesssible. Show the fields/properties `OrderNumber` and `OrderTotal`. Maybe `OrderTotal` is actually the number of orders per group(then use `Count()`). But this is not clear from your question and not really on topic here

Comment: Never mind, the "ToList" at the end didn't have parentheses.  All good now.  Thanks!

Comment: @j.kiel: ah yes, i had fixed that already in my code. Thought you have seen this

Answer (score 0):

it will be `x.Key.OrderNumber` and `x.Key.OrderTotal`. Read in the help how GroupBy works.