# Linq group by more than two 2 values in datagridviewrow

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, group-by

Ihave the following datagridView :

[image: datagridview]

I want to make a **group by** these three columns :
`annee` and `mois` and `jour`

I tried this:

```
bool isActiveDuplicate = dg_PanRejet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["isActive"].Value.ToString() == "2")
                .GroupBy(u => new { u.Cells["annee"], u.Cells["jour"], u.Cells["mois"] })
                .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

And this:

```
bool isActiveDuplicate = dg_PanRejet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["isActive"].Value.ToString() == "2")
                .GroupBy(u => u.Cells["annee"].Value, u=> u.Cells["jour"].Value, u=>u.Cells["fd"].Value)
                .Any(u => u.Count() > 1);
```

but i am stuck with this following error:

> Anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member
>   access expression

whereas i don't want to create a specific class to match the result of the query because i will only use it once.

Can i achieve this group by without being forced to use member access to a type of a class that i will be creating?

I have to mention that **it works fine** when i group by one or at most 2 cells like following:

```
bool duplicate_ista2 = dg_PanRejet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["annee"].Value.ToString() == "2000")
                .GroupBy(x => x.Cells["mois"].Value)
                .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

**EDIT**: this is different from this [suggested duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703034/linq-getting-customers-group-by-date-and-then-by-their-type) :

because here also we are doing group by 2 columns not more

Comment: give the new anonymous members names, for example: `new { annee = u.Cells["annee"], jour = u.Cells["jour"], mois = u.Cells["mois"] }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq Getting Customers group by date and then by their type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703034/linq-getting-customers-group-by-date-and-then-by-their-type)

Comment: @SimonPrice there too the grouping is done on 2 colummns not more. so, no it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ thank you anyway

Comment: whoever downgraded this question, can you please share with us why did you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make a group by these three columns : annee and mois and jour

Let's look at your **first implementation**.

```
bool isActiveDuplicate = dg_PanRejet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["isActive"].Value.ToString() == "2")
                .GroupBy(u => new { u.Cells["annee"], u.Cells["jour"], u.Cells["mois"] })
                .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Before even compiling it you should get a few errors, specifically:

```
 CS0746 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
```

In order to fix this problem, add some simple names for those members, for example:

```
  .GroupBy(u => new { annee = u.Cells["annee"], jour = u.Cells["jour"], mois = u.Cells["mois"] })
```

Also, I don't think you may understand, that `linq` statement is trying to group by `DataGridViewRow.Cells` object, not what you may want, you are more than likely looking for the value of the cells.

Your **second implementation breakdown**.

```
bool isActiveDuplicate = dg_PanRejet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["isActive"].Value.ToString() == "2")
                .GroupBy(u => u.Cells["annee"].Value, u=> u.Cells["jour"].Value, u=>u.Cells["fd"].Value)
                .Any(u => u.Count() > 1);
```

You should get a little different error from the first one. It may be along the lines of:

```
 Can't convert lambda expression to type 'IEqualityComparer<object>...`
```

The reason is because the `GroupBy` expression is trying to convert the lambda expression to a `IEqualityComparer<object>`.

**Here's one way to get your results:** (comments in code)

```
 // Get all records that match your where clause into a IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>.
        var records = dg_PanRejet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["annee"].Value.ToString() == "2000");
        // Get an IEnumerable<IGrouping<a, DataGridViewRow>> of anonymous type that matches our group by.
        var ienRecords =
            from rec in records
            group rec by new
            {
                annee = rec.Cells["annee"].Value,
                jour = rec.Cells["jour"].Value,
                mois = rec.Cells["mois"].Value
            };
        // Finally do we have duplicates?
        bool dup = ienRecords.Count() > 0;
```

In the above code, `ienRecords` contains all records (IEnumerable>) that are grouped by those three fields. `dup` just holds the operator check of making sure there are duplicates.